Pass AzureML job's name to pipeline
I have a scheduled AzureML pipeline. Every run of the pipeline gets an autogenerated name in the AzureML UI. I'd like to pass this name to the pipeline. How could I do that?
The scheduled pipeline is created as follows:
step = CommandStep(command="myscript.sh --job-name=<AZUREML JOB NAME>")
pipeline = Pipeline(workspace, [step])
published_pipeline = pipeline.publish(name='my pipeline')
schedule = Schedule.create(workspace=workspace, pipeline_id=published_pipeline.id, ...)

I would like to pass the run name create by AzureML e.g. as a command line parameter as in the example above.

What type of job, is it command job ?how you created that job, using python sdk v2?

Add the code or steps you used to create the job.

You can get the latest pipeline object and take the name of it. run.name then you pass it in your step.

From within an AzureML pipeline (SDK v2), you can read the run_id from an environment variable and then get the display name as follows
client = MLClient( ... )
job = client.jobs.get(os.environ["AZUREML_RUN_ID"])
job.display_name


The pipeline is referenced with run id/job name.

If you are using sdk v2, use below code.
pipeline_job = ml_client.jobs.create_or_update(
pipeline_job, experiment_name="17 dec"
)
pipeline_job.name

Here, you use the pipeline job object after submitting the job to get the job name.
Output:

OR
In sdk v1
run = Run.get_context()
run_id = run.id

Next, pass this id to your step job.
step = CommandStep(command=f"myscript.sh --job-name={run_id }")

